# Substitution to get separable equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with converting

$$y' = \sin(x-y)$$

to separable form. What I've done so far is to apply the difference formula:

$$y' = \sin(x)\cos(y) - \cos(x)\sin(y)$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is to get rid of the $\sin$ argument: $ z = x-y$ then $y' = 1-z'$ and you have
$$
1-z' = \sin z \Leftrightarrow z' = 1-\sin z
$$
which is an ODE with separated variables and you can easily integrate it.